# XMLReader SSL Version

Tags: php, openssl, sslv3

I have a legacy system using XMLReader to access a website and it recently started failing with this error:

```
Warning: XMLReader::open(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(): Failed to enable crypto
```

From my understanding, the issue is that the website stopped accepting sslv3. I'm just wondering if there is a way to tell XMLReader to use a different SSL version, or would an update to OpenSSL be required? As mentioned its a legacy system and updating the packages isn't an easy process, so I'm trying to see if there is another way to go about fixing this.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling SSL checking:

```
stream_context_set_default(['ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Had to update that line to this for it to run:

`stream_context_set_default(array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)));`

But I still get the same SSL errors, so it doesn't look like that fixes it.

Comment: One option could also be:
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

Or you still have to update openssl, it can also solve the problem above.